# what is Fortran equivalent of the following statement

Tags: string, fortran, variable-assignment

I want to assign a formatted string to a variable.  For example, I would write the following in Python:

```
my_score = 100
line = "score = %d" % my_score 
print(line)
```

This will print the following:

```
score = 100
```

How to write the same in Fortran?

Comment: Can you show us the Fortran code that you have attempted to write?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The direct implementation of Your code would be something like:

```
program test

   integer :: score
   character(len=30) :: line

   score = 100

   write(line, '(a, i3)') "score = ", score

   print '(a)', line

end program test
```